# JQuery Multiple If Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, logical-operators

I have the following code block which works great:

```
jQuery(".archive-job_listing-layout").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (!jQuery("body").hasClass('post-type-archive-job_listing')) 
            return;
        console.log("Click " + jQuery(this).data('style'));
        console.log(jQuery(window).width());
        if (jQuery(this).data('style') == "grid" && jQuery(window).width() < 800) {
            jQuery("ul.job_listings").css('display','block');
            jQuery("table#wswp-header-row").hide().remove();
            jQuery(".table_padding").hide().remove();
            return;
        }

        layout_to_table("click");
    })
});
```

I want to do is add another line which like:

```
if (!jQuery("body").hasClass('archive tax-job_listing_type'))
return;
```

but adding this breaks the code. I've tried using If Else, Or (||) And (&&), but nothing works.
If i substitute `'post-type-archive-job_listing'` with `'archive tax-job_listing_type'` the code also works fine, i just can't seem to get both of these lines of code to work at the same time.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle, I am unable to recreate the error.  Also, when you say it "breaks the code", what happens?  Are you getting a javascript error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: @cport1: It's not needed here.

Comment: `archive tax-job_listing_type` is not a class. That line is probably always going to evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
if(!jQuery("body").hasClass('archive tax-job_listing_type') && !jQuery("body").hasClass('post-type-archive-job_listing'))
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps separating with a few more parenthesis will work out for you:

```
if (!(jQuery("body").hasClass('post-type-archive-job_listing')) || !(jQuery("body").hasClass('archive tax-job_listing_type'))) 
        return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `is()` which accepts multiple selectors. Will act like `or` when more than one selector is passed to it

```
if(!jQuery("body").is('.archive tax-job_listing_type, .post-type-archive-job_listing'))
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5s8zgLoe/)**</kbd>